# How exactly trading of Bitcoin does?

Tags: transactions

How exactly trading of Bitcoin does? Is it just like a trading of shares of any company listed on stock exchange? Can anyone explain its transaction in detail?? Is there any Transaction fees or trading margin like stock exchange?

Answer (score 1):

When trading bitcoin on exchanges you trade directly at the exchange (not through a broker). Another big difference is that everything at an exchange is visible publicly, this includes the current orderbook and a recent set of historical trades.

What is features are supported and what the fees are depend on the exchange, a few big exchanges are:

- [bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net/): They only support trading assets that you own, you can make limit orders or market orders. Margin trading is not supported.
- [bitfinex](https://www.bitfinex.com/): They support the same as bitstamp as well as margin orders.
- [kraken](https://www.kraken.com/): Similar as bitstamp, but also supports other cryptocurrencies.

Besides the top few, there are also exchanges that do not have markets with FIAT money, the biggest one here is [poloniex](https://poloniex.com/) (which supports margin trading).